# pass Angular variables to Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I load data via Angular ajax. How can I pass returned results to laravel `@include` partial?

Angular:

```
$scope.findItem = function(itemId) {
    $scope.spinner = true;
    $http.get('item/' + itemId).success(function(results) {
        $scope.spinner = false;
        $scope.results = results[0];
    });
};
```

html:

```
<div ng-init="findItem(185)">
    <span ng-show="spinner" class="spinner"></span>
    <div ng-hide="results == undefined">
        @include('partials.item', {{ results }}) // <- I want to pass 'results' here
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do that. But you can just include the results variable as javascript in your `partials.item` view. So your HTML would look like this:

```
<div ng-init="findItem(185)">
    <span ng-show="spinner" class="spinner"></span>
    <div ng-hide="results == undefined">
        @include('partials.item')
    </div>
</div>
```

And your `partials.item` view would have angular variables instead of laravel variables:

```
@{{results}}
```

Instead of

```
{{$results}}
```

Make sense?

Comment: I'd considered such option, but the only thing I don't know how to go about in such situation is that I load this partial from two different pages, in one I do it with angular, in another with laravel only. So if I change laravel variables to angular, then I will not be able to load it via laravel.

Comment: Ok, so in your view, try using this: `{{$results or '{{results}}'}}`. You may still need to escape, I'm not sure. If so: `{{$results or '@{{results}}'}}`